# Using Mule simple flow timeouts over slow network with Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: mule, mulesoft

Using Mule, I am testing timeout limits in Mule.
The mule version is 4.5.3
The  HTTP connector version is 1.9

Here's a link to the the test url I'm using https://throttletest-cvg5tp.5sc6y6-4.usa-e2.cloudhub.io/throttle

I'm sending a simple request over slow network speeds. I'm using Postman and throttling the network speed by using NetLimiter. It works without Netlimeter and when i set the speed to about 3kbs a second. If I set it to anything lower it becomes inconsistent. IT doesn't work at all if I set it to 500b/s.
I have also tried without netlimeter and setting up a QoS polict and it has similar results.

I keep getting "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT x.xx.xx.xx:443" after about 20 seconds, even though I have set the timeout to be larger.
Below is the Mule configuration of the app I'm using to test it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:cluster="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/cluster" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <configuration doc:name="Configuration" doc:id="f1852376-1b82-465b-81ce-2893baa8d050" defaultResponseTimeout="500000" shutdownTimeout="500000" defaultTransactionTimeout="5000">
    </configuration>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="505ed808-1a73-43bc-b51b-f1875ec92dfe" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" connectionIdleTimeout="500000" readTimeout="500000">
        </http:listener-connection>
    </http:listener-config> 
    <flow name="throttletestFlow" doc:id="ec3ca942-4c35-4f50-b88c-220bc3ef9d32" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="b7dbab9d-e916-431e-86fc-2c000e08cda6" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/throttle">
    </http:listener>
        <set-payload value="hello world" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="c1296134-c3b4-409b-9fa8-f7ea7188bd97" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reviewing the following links might help you to improve the question: [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular reproduction instructions are not complete: which Mule version and patch level? HTTP connector version? Where are you deploying locally, a server, CloudHub 1/2, Runtime Fabric? How is Netlimiter configured? Have you tried without HTTPS? Without Netlimiter?

Comment: Also please don't say MuleSoft if you are referring to Mule. MuleSoft is the company name, Mule is the product name. Specifically you are using a Mule 4.x version.